# Flot not rendering correctly on PhantomJS

Tags: phantomjs, flot

I am using phantomJS to automate the process of rendering Flot graphs. The issue is when I run the application on Firefox or Chrome the graphs is displayed with border and gridlines. Whereas when I automate using phantomJS the border and gridlines is not visible. Can anyone help me out ?

[Graph rendered by Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VcAy0.png)

[Graph Rendered by PhantomJS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qf6TD.png)